# Is it possible to programmatically retrieve this text using the windows api?

Tags: winapi, pywin32

I know it's possible to programmatically retrieve text #2 (refer to image below) using `win32gui.GetWindowText(handle)`. I could not find a function to retrieve text #1, is there still a way to retrieve this text programmatically?

Text #1 appears if you hover over a taskbar icon for a few seconds.

Alternatively, does anyone know what these kind of popups are called? That would help me in my search also.

[image: Texts]

Comment: I think it's the other way around. You can retrieve Text#1 with `GetWindowText`, it will also show up in TaskManager. Text#2 is probably custom drawn, it can't be retrieved, not easily (it just happens to be application's name in this case). Text#1 is shown in "Tooltip winodw", Text#2 is drawn in Thumbnail.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That's not the case. `GetWindowText` retrieves the following text for me: `Windows Media Player`, not text #1. I've just run my helper script to make sure. The same text, `Windows Media Player` appears in the task manager, not text #2.

Comment: There is more than one Media Player Window, you are looking at the first window which is called "Windows Media Player".

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've made a small helper program that iterates over all windows and their child windows using `EnumWindows` and `EnumChildWindows`. Text #1 cannot be found anywhere in the output.

Comment: Sorry you are right. What I wrote earlier was rubbish, I was looking at VLC media player, I just assumed they will be similar.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [the official Windows Media Player SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get information about the currently plying song instead of trying to wrestle it out with `GetWindowText()` (which [I don't think even works across-process boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) of a tooltip (which are owned windows, not child windows). [This method seems to be the right one (but I wouldn't know for sure).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Absolutely, I was researching in how to use the Windows Media Player COM interface. Unfortunately, it has been absolute hell. Most properties or methods that "should be there" don't exist at all, especially the "requestMediaAccessRights" method, which should give access to methods/properties you normally won't have access to.

The method you linked seems to be the right one but it always returns null for me anyhow. Most other methods are simply inaccessible.